# YouTubePlayerSupportFragment video goes black after scrolling recycler view but audio keeps playing

Tags: java, android, youtube

So i am using YouTubePlayerSupportFragment to play a youtube video inside a cell in recycler view.

But when i start scrolling down and going back to the cell with YouTubePlayerSupportFragment the video goes black but i can still hear the audio playing.

Has anyone had the same problem and managed to solve it?

```
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder) {
   holder.youTubePlayerFragment.initialize("KEY",
                new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
                                                        YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
                        youTubePlayer.cueVideo("ID");
                        youTubePlayer.play();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {
                        if (provider != null) {

                        }
                    }
                });
}
```

Comment: You need to control the touch events. When user scrolls, pause the video simply .

Comment: @Jyoti JK It still goes black when the cell is not visible

Answer (score 2):

u have to pause or stop the video when view is not visible to user like this:-

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
 if (!isVisibleToUser) {
      youTubePlayer.stop(); // or pause 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to fix this by using onViewDetachedFromWindow and onViewAttachedToWindow functions of the adapter.

In onViewAttachedToWindow I add the YouTubePlayerSupportFragment and initialize the video and in onViewDetachedFromWindow i pause the video and remove the fragment.

This solved ths issue for me.